# Machine Learning Multiclass Classification for thousands of Classes

Tags: .net, sql-server, machine-learning

I have Entities with 1 to 10 attributes describing each of them and I need Machine Learning to suggest best matching Class for each Entity. Sounds straightforward, but there are about one hundred thousand Classes at the moment. Can you please suggest a Machine Learning algorithm (ideally available on SQL Server, Azure or as .NET library) or a stand-alone tool for massive Multiclass Classification?

Comment: Found this promising research: [Learning compact class codes for fast inference in large multi class classification](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~flach/ecmlpkdd2012papers/1125550.pdf). I wonder whether there are any implementations available?